# Generate WKT from geometry type in SQL Server

Tags: geometry, kml, well-known-text, sql-server-spatial

I have a bunch of polygon data in a SQL Server database.
Most of the data was created in Google Earth and exported as KML, then imported to SQL Server as WKT before conversion to geometry.
Each record in the database has the following fields

- [id] int not null,
- [label] nvarchar(255) not null,
- [boundary_wkt] nvarchar(max),
- [boundary_geo] geometry,
- [fk_id] int not null

But some of the data has come from 3rd party sources and we don't hold the WKT data for these, just the geometry.

As we also have a WKT -> KML conversion routine, I don't currently have the ability to display this 3rd party data in Google Earth.

Is there a way to convert geometry data into WKT?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stastext-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Besides the Microsoft ST_AsText equivalent?